# What is the correct grammar to use with future perfect tense

Tags: grammar, future-tense, future-perfect

I have the following sentence:

> After you'll have listened to the talk **you’ll be** an expert on
>   debugging CD related issues like DOM and bindings updates and **will be**
>   able to architect performance efficient applications.

I have some doubts regarding the bolded part. I use simply future sense there. Is it OK?

Comment: No. It should be **After you have listened** or **After you listen** .... **you will be...**

Comment: The problem here **is** the future perfect tense ("After you will have listened...") which isn't used in that situation. Perhaps that's causing the confusion over the other verbs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the present simple to refer to the future, not will, in adverbial clauses introduced by time conjunctions such as **after, before, when, and until:**

• After you go another 50 metres, you'll see a path to your left.
• When you see Dennis, tell him he still owes me some money.
• Wait here until I call you.

and in conditional clauses with **if, unless, in case, and provided**:

• Let me know if he says anything interesting.
• Provided the right software is available, I should be able to solve the problem.
• I'll bring a compass in case we get lost.

**Martin Hewings** *Advanced Grammar in Use 1ed.*

Comment: Thanks for adding the reference. Could you edit to use `>` to indicate exactly what you have quoted, please? Also, if the work is available online, a link would be very useful. (Note: if you use `*` for bullets, the list is formatted automagically. HTML bullets don't do that.)

Comment: There are three editions of the book. I strongly recommend the first one.

Comment: thanks, so what's the difference between `After you have listened or After you listen .... you will be..`?

Comment: The same as between a planned action and completed one. You are going to listen to the talk and you are going to have listened to that talk. Not very much difference in this case, imo. But I'm not a native speaker, so I might be wrong.

Comment: okay, thanks, I'll use the `After you have listened` option

Comment: Certainly 'After you'll have listened' needs correcting. But OP is asking about the **bolded** strings.

Comment: It's OK with them.